# RESTRICT approval of custom list item creation to SPECIFIC USERS ONLY

Tags: workflow, permissions, custom-list, approval

I want to restrict approval of items by specific users, depending on the user input in a custom list.
I used the "Start Approval" method of a workflow (Sharepoint Designer) and that works perfectly.

It binds the approver to a task in order to validate the item.

But on the approver side, I cannot click the button Approve/Reject (greyed out)
So what I did was checking the "require content approval" option in my list settings -> Versioning menu
Now everyone can simply Accept or Reject every item , and that's not what i want !

Thanks in advance for the help

EDIT : I'm now using Sharepoint designer with this code :
[image]

The task is assigned to Richard Bertrand. But EVERYONE can just approve or reject the task..
How do I restrict approval of specific items to SPECIFIC USERS ONLY

Answer (score 0):

You should create a SharePoint Group that don't have Manage List permission. Now add all users who can't approve the items into that group.

Now go and remove the users from the current groups.

Comment: I tried to add a group but I have no "Manage List" permission. Besides, my workflow generates 2 types of approvals depending on the price of the item created. So when the price is more than 1000 the approval request is sent to another user. I don't think i can do that with your solution

Comment: I installed and configured workflow manager that permits me to create 2013 Sharepoint workflows type.

I used Start a task process with "myuser" (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome)

then a if Variable: Outcome equals Approved Set Workflow Status to Approved. The task assignment  works but I can approve the task with every user that has Contribute Permissions.... My question is still the same, how can I request approvals of specific items by specific users??

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm trying to achieve is simply not possible in Microsoft Sharepoint.

Instead I've created 2 differents custom lists with differents permissions, then created a workflow that copy every item submitted by a user into one of these lists, depending on fields values.